# How to delete all files in remote directory with rclone?

Tags: rclone

I use `rclone` with Ubuntu 12.04 to upload files from server to Google Drive. Everything works fine, but I can not figure out, with what command I can delete all files in directory. I have a remote called `gdrive`.

I tried using empty path:

```
root@machine:~$ rclone purge gdrive:
2015/09/13 00:54:02 Attempt 1/3 failed with 1 errors and: Can't purge root directory
2015/09/13 00:54:02 Attempt 2/3 failed with 1 errors and: Can't purge root directory
2015/09/13 00:54:02 Attempt 3/3 failed with 1 errors and: Can't purge root directory
2015/09/13 00:54:02 Failed to purge: Can't purge root directory
```

I tried using `*`:

```
root@machine:~$ rclone purge gdrive:*
2015/09/13 00:56:49 Attempt 1/3 failed with 1 errors and: Couldn't find directory: "*"
2015/09/13 00:56:49 Attempt 2/3 failed with 1 errors and: Couldn't find directory: "*"
2015/09/13 00:56:49 Attempt 3/3 failed with 1 errors and: Couldn't find directory: "*"
2015/09/13 00:56:49 Failed to purge: Couldn't find directory: "*"
```

Using purge to delete directories and files I know the name of works fine, but I can not guess how to delete all files in the root directory at once and the documentation on rclone's commands is poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for more information on rclone I stumbled on your question. What I thought of is to sync with a empty directory, as of:

rclone sync /path/to/a/empty/folder gdrive:

Theoretically it could work, going with the written on http://rclone.org/docs/ as premise:
"Sync the source to the destination, changing the destination only... Destination is updated to match source, including deleting files if necessary."
It's just a workaround and I haven't tested it, just thought it'd be good to mention. Good luck :)

Comment: I just tested it, it works! It is not exactly what I was looking for, but thanks and vote up. I can keep an empty folder ready for this occasion.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative would be to use

```
rclone delete gdrive:
```

Which will delete all the files on gdrive:

It won't delete the directories though - rclone doesn't manage those properly yet (See [rclone issue #100](https://github.com/ncw/rclone/issues/100) for more info).

Anyway, if you'd like rclone purge to work on the root of drive then I suggest you [make an issue](https://github.com/ncw/rclone/issues/new).

Hope that helps!

PS I'm the author of rclone ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and rclone, sure I will make an issue if that helps.

Comment: Deleting file by file is so slow in huge folders with tiny files